# Run CMake code only during generation

Tags: cmake

I am quite sure that this is a bit of a antipattern but I would like to run part of a CMake script only during generation. I want to use CMake to generate a template project with some dependencies. The script needs to copy some files and change a few lines (file names and part of their content). So what I would like to do is to delay the renaming etc. to the generation. The workflow would then be to take the template (CMakeLists.txt), configure with a generator, set the project name, set the path to dependencies and the hit generate to get the ready-to-build project.

Is there a way to run code only on generation? I know that scripts could do the same but I would like to use CMake with this one.

**EDIT 2**

I removed the original edit. Here is the source structure of the simple example:

```
- Trunk
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - ProjectFile.cpp
    - ProjectFile.h
- Build
```

The ProjectFile.h and ProjectFile.cpp are template files which have to be moved to Build, have to be renamed and some content has to be changed. The initial idea however was that the files locate in Trunk are not modified.

I wrote this mini CMakeLists.txt file:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1) #may be adjusted later on, current WIP runs on 3.5.1

set(PRJ_NAME ProjectName CACHE STRING  "Project Name")  
project(${PRJ_NAME})

file(COPY "ProjectFile.h" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\\Source")
file(COPY "ProjectFile.cpp" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\\Source")

# copy template source / header files to binary dir, create a .def file
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\\Source\\${PRJ_NAME}.def" "LIBRARY ${PRJ_NAME}\nEXPORTS\nVSTPluginMain\nmain=VSTPluginMain" )
file(RENAME "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\\Source\\ProjectFile.h"   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\\Source\\${PRJ_NAME}.h")
file(RENAME "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\\Source\\ProjectFile.cpp" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\\Source\\${PRJ_NAME}.cpp")


# create the actual project
add_library(${PRJ_NAME} SHARED ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Source/${PRJ_NAME}.h ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Source/${PRJ_NAME}.cpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Source/${PRJ_NAME}.def)
```

In this example, I only worked on the copying and renaming of the files until I noticed the issue. Next to the .cpp and .h, a .def has to be created with the correct name. What is happening is that  the `file()` calles are done duiring configuration, I would like them to run doring generation so that the workflow would be:

```
- set a new build path
- hit configure, set the generator
- adjust some settings, the project name, dependencies,...
- hit generate, get the build-ready project
```

I understand that this is a misuse of CMake and the correct method would be to somehow split this in two: 1) generate a CMake project with a script that sets the project name 2) create a project with CMake the usual way.

Comment: Can give some example what you want to achieve, what you tried and why it did not work? Currently, its too broad to answer.

Comment: What you describe sounds to me like a totally normal CMake pattern. That's why CMake does search for source files in `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` *and* `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` (e.g. [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) outputs the modified source files to `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`). So a `CMakeLists.txt` is a template for a project itself (including modifying/configuring source files). If you give more details on what kind of file renaming/modifying source files you want to do, we/I could give an example how to implement this.

Comment: I don't see the point in renaming the files. For example, you could use [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) to create your file (with the necessary variable substitutions) in your build directory. You didn't explicitly mention that, but what you should definitely avoid is modifying anything in the source directory. I am afraid your problem is still not enough clearly explained

Comment: Mhh, you'll have to wait for me to get back home then. :) I cant access the CMake script I wrote right now.

Comment: I was wondering if you do know about CMake's script mode `cmake -P ...`? I don't think you need a generator/compiler for you first step of creating an simple project environment.

Comment: @Florian I didn't knew about it, will have a look tomorrow. Meanwhile, I modified the question with the script I wrote originally. Hope this makes it a bit less confusing. Cheers!